# Better approximation of the subset in the membership oracle

Tags: approximation-algorithms, set-theory

A standard tool for estimating the size of a subset via membership oracle queries is given below.

**Lemma 2.8: .** Consider two (finite) sets $B ⊆ U$, where $n = |U|$. Let $ε ∈ (0, 1)$ and $γ ∈ (0, 1/2)$ be
parameters. Let $g > 0$ be a user-provided guess for the size of $|B|$. Consider a random sample $R$, taken
with replacement from $U$, of size $r = dc_5{ε^{−2}}
(n/g) \log γ^−1$, where $c_5$ is sufficiently large. Next, consider
the estimate $Y = (n/r)|R ∩ B|$ to $|B|$. Then, we have the following:
(A) If $Y < g/2$, then $|B| < g$,
(B) If $Y ≥ g/2$, then $(1 − ε)Y ≤ |B| ≤ (1 + ε)Y$.
Both statements above hold with probability $≥ 1 − γ$.

**Lemma 2.7:** Consider two sets $B ⊆ U$, where $n = |U|$. Let $ξ, γ ∈ (0, 1)$ be parameters, such that
$γ < 1/ \log n$. Assume that one is given an access to a membership oracle that, given an element $x ∈ U$,
returns whether or not $x ∈ B$. Then, one can compute an estimate $s$, such that $(1 − ξ)|B| ≤ s ≤
(1 + ξ)|B|$, and computing this estimate requires $O((n/ |B|)ξ^{−2}
\log γ^{−1}
)$ oracle queries. The returned
estimate is correct with probability $\ge 1- \gamma$.

The above lemma can be found in [Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07567.pdf) (Page 12, lemma 2.8).

The proof idea of lemma 2.7 is to call the lemma 2.8 for values $n/2^i$ where $i =1,2,3,\cdots,\log n $ with value $ε=0.5$.

**Question:** Is it possible to improve the approximation factor $ξ$ of the lemma 2.7?
I am thinking two directions given below:

1. Increase the size of $r$ (lemma 2.8).
2. To call lemma 2.8 more number of times (more than $O(\log n)$).

I am not getting how to proceed further.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by improving $\xi$ In Lemma 2.8? What kind of result are you hoping to get?